# Getting an error when try to substract : Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,3)

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

i got error when try to run my code below:

```
def h(x):
    global w
    return sum(np.transpose(w)*x)
    raise NotImplementedError()

def cost_func_linreg(X, y):
    m = len(y)

    for i in range(1, m+1):
        X_i = np.power(X, i)
        c= np.sum(np.square(h(X_i) - y))
    return (1/(2*m))*c
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

it works fine if the input is below:

```
w, X, y = [-1, 0], [[1,1],[0,1]], [-1,0]
```

but, i got an error when the input is below:

```
w, X, y = [1, 1, 2], [[1,1,1],[0,0,0]], [0,0]
cost_func_linreg(X,y)
```

it returns an error :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

it points out the error at :

```
----> 9         c= np.sum(np.square(h(X_i) - y))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear, what you want to have as a result, but try replacing `sum` with `np.sum` in h(x):

```
def h(x):
    global w
    return np.sum(np.transpose(w)*x)
```

At least it gives no error :)